Does penalizing the slope in Ridge/ Lasso regression has adverse effect based on the training data?
I have just started to learn ridge and lasso regression (by this YouTube video). To my understanding, these regressions are similar to linear regression, but we penalize the higher slope by the coefficient $\lambda$ to reduce overfitting. For the bivariate case, we want to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y)^2+\lambda(\text{slope of the line})^2$ by ridge regression.
But let's assume that in the following plot, the red circles are my training data and the blue circles are my test data. Assuming that after penalizing the slope, the best fitted line is the green line, this way the performance of the linear model gets worse. (On the other hand, if the blue circles where training data, the fitted line would reduce the overfitting problem). I'm wondering in this case how Ridge (or Lasso regression) can reduce the over-fitting, as reducing the slope will result in adverse fit of the line.


Why downvote? I shared what I've understand about Ridge and Lasso regression from this YouTube tutorial. I'll appreciate if you can identify my misunderstanding.

If your test data set is not the same as your training data set, then you are breaking a fundamental assumption of statistical methods. You should better understand means let alone linear regression

@seanv507 Thanks! In particular I don't completely understand the usefulness of reducing the slope of the fitted line. How it reduce the over fit?

First, if these are the training and test data (or if they look anything like this) then your system of randomizing observations to "train" and "test" is seriously messed up, nothing will work well, and you'd best start over.  Training and test data should be randomly split and, if they are, then, while it is not quite impossible to get a pattern like you got, it is very, very, very unlikely.
Second, I would be careful about learning statistics from YouTube videos. I haven't watched the one you linked to. The description looks OK, but anyone can post a YouTube. Read papers and books. Or ask on CrossValidated because, while anyone can answer on CV, wrong answers often get corrected.
Third, one of the main points of the Lasso is to correct for overfitting that occurs when we use model building methods such as stepwise selection or bivariate screening. You can get details of this overfitting in Frank Harrell's book Regression Modeling Strategies (which is a good book to have, for many reasons) or, if you want something shorter, in my paper Stopping Stepwise: Why Stepwise Selection is Bad and what to Use Instead (available in a bunch of spots on the web).

+1 just for the advice Read papers and books. Or ask on CrossValidated because, while anyone can answer on CV, wrong answers often get corrected.

Thanks! I agree with you that YouTube videos are not a good way to learn statistics. But from some of the videos I've already watched, I think they can be a good starting point for building intuition by simplifying the subject. For example, StatQuest on YouTube seems to be good for beginners who have no idea about the subject.

If your train and testset are not similar, nothing makes sense. The whole idea of statistical learning, machine learning, it is all based on the idea the the test- and trainset are more or less similar. The adjusting of the coefficients in Lasso and ridge regression are not meant to address something like this.
Overfitting happens when your regression follows the testset too closely. By lowering the coeffients, complex and wild shapes are avoided. .
It is true that applying ridge regression can adversely affect the fit, in your example, assuming the train- and testset are similar (this picture is hard to look at for statisticians as-is :) ) - it would indeed lower the slope, which may not work out. However, in practice, it usually helps to use lasso or ridge.
